# OS X Mountain Lion: keyboard shortcut to move current window to another space

Tags: macos, keyboard, spaces, window-manager

In OS X Mountain Lion, is there a way I can assign a keyboard shortcut to move the active window to a specified space (or even the adjacent space if an arbitrary space can't be specified).

Ideally, the space to which the window is moved to, won't itself get activated in the process. That is, the window will simply disappear from the current space, while the current space won't itself change.

I am open to all options: AppleScript, objective C, tweaking with preferences etc.

Lack of this feature really gets in the way of the window management workflow!

Comment: Stumbled across this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308820/how-can-i-programatically-move-one-terminal-app-window-to-another-space). Can this be used to do what I need?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [sizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/).

sizeUp allows you to send the window to the next/previous space but also it has keyboard shortcuts for mounting a screen to the left or the right of a screen and sending it to the next/previous monitor.

[image: Screenshot of sizeUp configuration]

Comment: A similar app, not quite as full-featured, but free: http://spectacleapp.com

Answer (score 1):

[Slate](https://github.com/jigish/slate) might be an option for you:

> Slate is a window management application similar to Divvy and SizeUp (except better and free!). Originally written to replace them due to some limitations in how each work, it attempts to overcome them by simply being extremely configurable. As a result, it may be a bit daunting to get configured, but once it is done, the benefit is huge.
>
> Slate currently works on Mac OS X 10.6 and above

Comment: grgarside: Got it, thanks for the feedback
@patrix: Thanks for the quality edit

Answer (score 0):

[Divv](http://mizage.com/divvy/) is a game-changer.

Give it a try! :)